# Is there a universal way to get the name of a component field?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when I work with different plugins, I often want to change a specific value in a component from that plugin. And it is always a lengthy trial and error phase until I find out, how to address the value.

**Example**
Currently, I'm working with the Dreamteck Splines plugin.
One of the components is the Spline Positioner which has under the headline Tracing a expandable section called Motion in which is the headline Position which has the sub headline Offset and in it is the field "X" which I want to change.

So, I tried it with ...

```
GetComponent<SplinePositioner>().offset.x
GetComponent<SplinePositioner>().offsetX
GetComponent<SplinePositioner>().position.offset.x
```

and so on ... but everything is wrong.

In a perfect world, I could hover over any field in the inspector and a tooltip is shown with the way, I can address this specific field. But this isn't the perfect world ;)

So, how you deal with that, when you you don't find it in the documentation of the plugin?

Thank you!

Comment: If that field is "public" you can address it and set value , when it is private field , sorry you can't

Comment: Pretty unclear what exactly you are asking .. note that the fields in the Inspector may be called different to the actual fields (e.g. `_myField` will be `My Field` in the Inspector) .. and even "worse" if there is a custom editor it may hide/add or completely rename fields .. so you can't rely on what the Inspector shows you ... Open your script in a serious IDE (Visual Studio, Rider, etc) and type `GetComponent<SplinePositioner>().` then it should show you what fields and properties exist

Comment: @TimChang .. well you can .. via reflection ;) The question is why would you do that? There is usually a reason why things are private

Comment: Note that even in a perfect world I'm pretty sure that I would not again write the fields name and way to access into the Tooltips ^^ It's for writing a description what this field does not how to access it by code ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found it through the suggestion list of Visual Studio code after typing in `GetComponent<SplinePositioner>().` First, this list felt a little generic, but after looking through it, entry for entry, I found my way. It was `GetComponent<SplinePositioner>().motion.offset.x` in the end.

Thank you @derHugo for getting me in the right direction :)